# how to fill only some specific items from access database into combobox in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

for example, i have a column called "Project" in database which contains project numbers like p1,p2 so on. "Project" column is linked with another column called "Tasks" in another table which contains t1,t2,t3 for p1 and t4,t5,t6 for p2 so on. 
so while execution when i select p1 in project field it should only display its related task numbers i.e. only t1,t2,t3 in "task" combo-box and when i select p2 it should display only t4,t5,t6.

now my problem is its displaying all the tasks from t1 to t6 in "task" combo-box instead of specific ones.

Any workable solution to this problem like code snippets and guidelines are appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: Just filter the list to match the selected project in the project field.

Comment: i don't know to filter, can u post a code snippet  of it.

Comment: E.g. using LINQ: `DisplayedTasks = allTasks.Where(task => task.ProjectId == SelectedProject.ProjectId)`

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below example

```
Project Table:

    ID ProjectName
    1   P1
    2   P2
```

Task Table:

```
ID ProjectID TaskName
1   1          T1
2   1          T2
3   1          T3
4   2          T4
5   2          T5
6   2          T6
```

Pass the project ID as parameter to the query

```
Select TaskName from Task Where ProjectID = 1 -- @ProjectID
```

Result :

```
ID
T1
T2
T3
```

OR

If you have all the values in the object then you can use LINQ.

Include the namespace System.LINQ

```
int selectProjectID = 1;
var projectTask = task.where(x => x.ProjectID == ProjectID).ToList();
```

bind the projectTask to dropdown

Comment: I think you wanted assign T4, T5 and T6 to P2 I am just guessing but only in that way your answer is right.

Comment: you are correct . thanks i will update it. I don't have reputation to upvote your comment. Will do it in future :)

Comment: thanks, i will try this out. I don't have reputation to upvote your comment. Will do it in future :)

Answer (score 0):

private void cbx_pbnum_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 List lstprodbacklog = obcpb.Where(p => p.ProjectTableId.ToString() == cbx_projectname.SelectedValue.ToString()).ToList();

```
        if(lstprodbacklog.Count>0)
        {

            cbx_pbnum.Items.Clear();
            foreach (ProductBacklog pb in lstprodbacklog)
            {
                if (cbx_projectname.SelectedValue.ToString() == pb.ProjectTableId.ToString())
                {
                    cbx_pbnum.Items.Add(pb.PBNum);                           
                }
            }
        }
```

}